# Do firefighters contitute a legislative power?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

According to this article [ref here](https://dcdirtylaundry.com/new-york-fire-commissioners-call-for-new-9-11-investigation/), [ref here](https://www.globalresearch.ca/new-york-area-fire-commissioners-make-history-call-new-911-investigation/5684982), [ref here](https://www.zerohedge.com/health/new-york-area-fire-commissioners-demand-new-911-investigation) and [ref here:](https://www.ae911truth.org/news/540-new-york-area-fire-commissioners-make-history-call-for-new-9-11-investigation)

> ...History has just been made, as the first legislative body in the
>   country officially announces their support for reopening the 9/11
>   investigation. Citing “overwhelming evidence” of preplanted
>   explosives, the fire commissioners of Franklin Square and Munson...

Video of the whole event [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qM9CJRClLOk)

> ...the Franklin Square and Munson Fire District, which oversees a
>   volunteer fire department serving a hamlet of 30,000 residents just
>   outside of Queens, New York, became the first legislative body in the
>   country to officially support a new investigation into the events of
>   9/11...

**What legislative body is that?** It is said that they support a new independent investigation but whose responsibility is to start an investigation like that? Are firefighters a legislative body in the USA?

[Lawyers' Committee for 9/11 Inquiry](https://www.lawyerscommitteefor9-11inquiry.org/) have been trying the open a new investigation without result for years why is it any different now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99022/discussion-on-question-by-pbxman-do-firefighters-contitute-a-legislative-power).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fire district has five elected members who oversee the organization's $2.5 million annual budget. They are elected officials who vote on policy, but it's a stretch to refer to them as a "legislative body." Most fire departments in the United States are divisions of other government agencies and do not have their own elected officials. Here's a more detailed explanation of the Franklin Square and Munson Fire District from a [New York state government report](https://www.osc.state.ny.us/localgov/audits/firedists/2017/franklinsquare-munson.pdf) (PDF):

> The Franklin Square and Munson Fire District (District) is a district
>   corporation of the State, distinct and separate from the hamlet of
>   Franklin Square, Nassau County, in which it is located. The District
>   covers an area of about three square miles consisting of Franklin
>   Square, Garden City South and parts of West Hempstead, and serves
>   about 30,000 residents. It has approximately 110 active volunteer
>   members. The Board of Fire Commissioners (Board) is composed of five
>   elected members and is responsible for the District’s overall
>   financial management and safeguarding its resources. The Board
>   appoints a Treasurer and a Secretary. The Treasurer acts as the
>   District’s chief fiscal officer and is responsible for the receipt and
>   custody of District funds, disbursing and accounting for those funds
>   and meeting any other reporting requirements. The Secretary is
>   responsible for keeping a complete and accurate record of the
>   proceedings of each Board meeting and all Board-adopted rules and
>   regulations. The District’s 2016 general fund budget appropriations
>   totaled $2,520,280, which were funded primarily by real property
>   taxes.

Comment: In WA, it's less of a stretch since a fire district is officially a political subdivision of the state, on a par with a town, having the power of eminent domain and the ability to regulate within their prescribed domain. Presumably you would call a city council a "legislative body". NY may be different.

Comment: @user6726 thanks for the background! I wasn't aware they had so much power.

Answer (score -1):

A legislative body is a group that convenes to vote and pass laws.

Firefighters are not a legislative body, but a board of commissioners that oversees a fire department is.